# My LAMP server is getting hammered with traffic, how can I see what's causing the load?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php

We're getting tons of traffic but it's causing the site to respond extremely slowly, or not at all. I'm in WHM checking out the load, the top processes, etc but I can't seem to find exactly *what* the problem is.

How can I see what is being accessed in real-ish time? If I know that I can disable all sorts of features and save the whole of the site.

http://www.districtlines.com - click sparingly if you don't mind, I'm dyin' here!

Comment: OS, Software, Logs? Are you sure your MySQL server config is okay? RAM usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first stop should be your apache access logs. The location of these will vary depending on your configuration, but `/var/log/httpd/` (or `/var/log/apache2`, depending on distro) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can install apachetop

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/monitor-your-website-in-real-time-with-apachetop/

Answer (score 0):

Try `netstat -nt | grep :80` as a starting point.  This will pick up connections which haven't hit the access logs, as well as connections which have recently be closed.

Try   `netstat -nt  | grep 208.87.33.150:80 | cut -c 44-64 | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` to get counts by recent connections.  Check the IP address I used.

EDIT: Changing your accesslog configuration to record response time (%D or %T) instead of ident name (%l) will allow you to collect data on which URL patterns are slowest.  Doing so when the whole site is slow may not provide useful statistics.

Use top to ensure you are using a significant amount of swap space.  If you have a memory leak then limiting MaxRequestsPerChild to 100 or 100 may help until you find and fix the problem.

Comment: netstat is certainly a useful tool, but it's not going to tell him what portions of his site he'll be able to disable to improve performance (which is a goal he stated).

Comment: @ErikA A sudden increase in traffic may signify a DOS.  netstat can help identify this issue.  I have updated my response with some server specific hints.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable cause of the problem will be Mysql. Enable slow query log on the mysql server and analyse the slow queries on how they can be improved by indexes etc.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html

A performance improvement tip.

While opening your site in firebug, a Firefox extension, I see most of the requests are for static content i.e images. Why don't you use a seperate domain i.e. static.districtlines.com and use a light weight webserver like nginx or lighttp to server those requests or offload it to amazonaws like you are for some requests.